# JDeveloper and ADF view criteria

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am new to ADF and JDeveloper. I am trying to create a view criteria and query panel with table using JDEveloper 11g. Right now I am able to create the view criteria, but all my search fields are showing as plain text input boxes. I actually want one of them to be shown as drop down list and one to be shown as the "select many shuttle" component. 
Can anyone tell me how it can be done using JDeveloper/ADF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you define an LOV for the fields in the VO?
See if this video helps: [Dependent LOVs in an af:query component](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/dependent_lovs_in_an_afquery_c)

Answer (score 2):

1)Create a LOV for that attribute
2)Ensure that in the control hints of the attribute , the control type is "choice list".

Answer (score 1):

if you want a component as LOV then you have to create LOV on that attribute on ViewObject.
but you can not show shuttle in af:query component.

http://www.javadrive.co.in/shuttle_component_in_ADF.html

http://oracleadf-java.blogspot.in/2012/11/shuttle-component-in-oracle-adf-allow.html